# RadScheduler leading to massive ViewState size

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, viewstate, radscheduler

Currently for a month view for the RadScheduler I am using, there are anywhere between 90-400+ appointments. Not all of them are always shown but due to some filtering logic, they always need to be pulled back and bound to the control for filtering and business logic.

This is leading to a ViewState size of a whopping 2.34MB (even **AFTER** gzip compression on the page).

I've tried to set `EnableViewState = false` on the control which works fine for the appointment being bound every Postback. The issue arises when using the AdvancedEdit template that I have customized. There is a point where the page needs to post back in order to repopulate a dropdown on the popup for inserting/updating an appointment. Is there any way to make just the AdvancedEditForm persist but not the RadScheduler control?

Is there anything that can be done short of moving the ViewState to the SQL Server?

**EDIT** RadCompression module is **not** an option due to the RadScheduler being used with a DotNetNuke module.

Answer (score 0):

View state is actually that, the state of the current presentation. It's a great mechanism to prevent POSTback of the page back and forth but eventually leads to very heavy pages. If you were to put the viewstate in a SQL server or in session data, it wouldn't be a viewstate it would be a session based state or else you'd have to keep every possible viewstate you ever generated for everypage in your database. I smell a bad case of viewstate misunderstanding here...

What is the solution?

Rethink your structure, RAD is a great library to my knowledge, althought i haven't used it much since i'm in PHP. There are bound to be local events that could let your bind javascript code to events that happen in your RADScheduler althought i can't be sure.

Also note that your best bet is to post on Telerik's website instead. The userbase of Telerik might have a much better understanding of what you can do and not do for your case...

Good luck

Comment: There are purely client-side events that can be hooked into the RadScheduler control although it would take too much time at this point and would be highly untested. And I believe you are correct it would be considered a "session-state" at that point. I'm familiar with ViewState but highly *unfamiliar* with how you can persist it or modify how it's persisted. Also posting to the Telerik forums is next to useless. Their responses are templated and unhelpful, and not quick at all.

Comment: Can't really help you more than that considering i haven't done ASP nor RAD in more than 2 years :P good luck

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply anyway :)